# Check if an element is contained in the values ​(array) of a json column in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, where-clause

I have the following values ​​inside a cell of a json column in MySql:

```
{
    "produttori": [
        "8",
        "9"
    ],
    "articoli_alternativi": [
        "3",
        "9"
    ],
    "articoli_accessori": [
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8"
    ],
    "tecnologie": [],
    "fornitori": [
        "9",
        "8"
    ],
    "classificazioni": [
        "3",
        "4"
    ]
}
```

I would like to make a query that extracts data based on the existence of a value in the array at the `fornitori` key.
For now I've tried this:

```
query = 'SELECT nome, formulati_commerciali FROM articolo WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(dati, "$.fornitori"), "' + \
        value+'", "$")'
```

Which print is:

```
SELECT name, data FROM articolo WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.fornitori"), "8", "$")
```

Basically the condition is that `value` (`"8"`) must be inside the `fornitori` list, otherwise skips the element.

Unfortunately, the query did not produce any results.

I would like to know how you can formulate such a query in MySql. I will need them often!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT name, data 
FROM articolo 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data, '"8"', '$.fornitori')
```

The double quotes around `8` are important, in order to properly match the JSON data. On the other hand, the query consistently uses single quotes for string literals.

Comment: Sir `JSON_CONTAINS()` is a pre defined function?

Comment: @KUMAR https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains (man page is for 8.0 but function exists as of 5.7.8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT data
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT  @i := @i + 1 AS rn,
            JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data,CONCAT('$.fornitori[',@i-1,']'))) AS elm,
           data               
      FROM information_schema.tables 
     CROSS JOIN articolo 
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) r
  ) q
 WHERE elm = 8
```

in order to search for the spesific value within a spesific
array(`"fornitori"`)

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=98bfefa1515edeb729c2e4b2671b8406)</kbd>

Comment: [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) is much easier...